# SSH connection gets stuck when using jump host

Tags: networking, command-line, ssh

At my work, we have a jump host over which I must connect to the cluster. Usually, the connection statement would be

```
ssh -t herp@jumphost ssh cluster
```

Furthermore, this connection has to be made from within the companies VPN. Now, I want to connect to `cluster` using VS Code on Windows 10. This creates several problems. [This blog post](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks) suggests to use the ssh config file for this so I added the following lines to C:\Users\Herp\.ssh\config:

```
Host jumphost
   HostName jumphost
   User herp

Host cluster-work
   User herp
   HostName cluster
   ProxyCommand ssh -tt jumphost
```

Then, when I try to connect using `cmd.exe` or the `PowerShell` I get:

```
$ ssh cluster -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\Herp/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\Herp/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for cluster-work
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -tt jumphost
debug1: identity file [...]
[...]
debug1: identity file [...]
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
herp@jumphost's password: <I enter the PW>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: Last login: Mon Jun 28 20:50:42 2021 from <some IP>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1:
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to cluster:22 as 'herp'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Bad packet length 218783296.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: message authentication code incorrect
```

Sometimes, the last few lines are instead

```
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: Last login: Mon Jun 28 20:50:42 2021 from <some IP>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: \033]0;herp@cluster:~\033[?1034h[herp@cluster ~]$ SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: -bash: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1: command not found
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: \033]0;herp@cluster:~[herp@cluster ~]$
```

If I use `-t` instead of `-tt` in the `ProxyCommand`, the last few lines before and after I enter the password are

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
herp@jumphost's password: <I enter the PW>
-bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1\r': command not found
```

and then `cmd.exe` freezes so that I have to close the window.

How can I get this connection to work?

### Update

Using the `-J` flag instead of `-t` leads to:

```
> ssh -J herp@jumphost herp@cluster
herp@jumphost's password: <I enter the PW>
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
```

### Update 2

I repeated this in WSL with the same result. So this is not only a Windows 10 problem.

Comment: Any reason that you don't use `-J` instead?

Comment: @TomYan I uptdated my question

Comment: Have you removed `ProxyCommand ssh -tt jumphost` in the config file?

Comment: @TomYan Yes, I have

Comment: The linked article uses `ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump-box`. Your `ProxyCommand` line is very different. Why? AFAIK in this approach `-W %h:%p` is crucial.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `kex_echange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` after I enter the password.

Comment: Perhaps some misconfiguration on jump host? What platform is that ssh server set up on? Can you add its `sshd_config` to the post?

Comment: (1) Is `jumphost` configured to connect to `cluster` on a non-standard port? With `ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p …` you need to specify this port *locally*, so your local `ssh` knows it, so `%p` expands to it. It can be hardcoded in `ProxyCommand`. One way or another you need to know it if you want to use `ProxyCommand`. (2) When connecting "manually" with `ssh -t herp@jumphost ssh cluster`, how do you authenticate? I think with `ProxyCommand` you will need to authenticate from your local, so key(s)/agent on `jumphost` won't matter and this may be an issue when we make `ProxyCommand` work.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski (1) The port should be 22. This can be seen from the `-v` output when I connect manually. I tried hardcoding it but got the same result. (2) I use identity files for that. I have the same keyfile on my local machine that is located on `jumphost`.

Comment: I suspect `cluster:22` from your local output is meaningless because the local command you used did not use the config from the `jumphost`. Please execute `ssh -t herp@jumphost ssh -v cluster` and observe the port there.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I got this port by first connecting to the `jumphost` only and connecting from there to `cluster` manually. Either way, with your suggestion the port is also given as 22.

Comment: Instead of `ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jumphost` try `ProxyCommand ssh -q jumphost exec nc %h %p` . Any progress?